# NetSuite Workflow to run if Credit Card is updated

Tags: workflow, netsuite

I am trying to create a workflow that will run when a customer (or agent) updates a customer credit card.  I am able to test this and see the change using Scripting, but that won't work for the customer changed side.

Anyone know of a way to either run scripts on the customer center pages, or to run a script from a workflow?  Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: According to NetSuite this is currently not possible.  I'm trying it with custom forms now, instead of their built in ones.  If that works I'll post the method,for anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wound up creating a custom form not using NetSuite data, and then passing that data into an internal RESTlet.  That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you click on the "All Roles" checkbox in the Script Deployment page, it would make your script run for Customer Center.  Alternatively you can also just select the Customer Center role in the Roles field.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that.  Finally got a hold of the NetSuite support, and they told me how it is supposed to work.  Though, when I actually log in as the customer, the scripts do not run on the external pages.